# Setting a background image for an li element

Tags: jquery, html, css

How would you set a background image for an li element?

```
<div id="frame" class="frame bag_item">
    <ul class="slidee">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/womyhrd8/

Comment: Why did you tag this with Jquery? Do you want to set it with jquery? because this can be done very simply with css

Comment: Can it be done with CSS?

Comment: Yes, ill post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with CSS like any other element using `background` (or `background-image`):

```
.frame .slidee li {
    background: url("http://www.placecage.com/300/50") no-repeat; //add image
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px; //changed just for my example
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/womyhrd8/1/)

Comment: Can it be set to an individual `<li></li>` with an id

Comment: yeah absolutely, if an `li` has an `id` and you target that `id` in css it will only effect that one item